# Google calendar and client secrets with desktop app

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am trying to figure out how the oauth flow will work for my google calendar app. I have a desktop app which I will be distributing and which will be using google calendar. I know there's a client secrets, but I'd like to know if there's a way to request a token rather than sending the client secrets file along. My worry is that someone will just spam the calendar and my app won't work for anyone else. Is this a possibility? What solutions exist to mitigate this?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using OAuth2, the client secret is used to authenticate your app to Google, not vice versa. The OAuth2 server will only issue a token to an application that submits a correct client id and client secret (among other things).  This arrangement is (in part) precisely about making sure that someone else cannot (e.g.) "spam your calendar".  Otherwise, how is Google to know that the requesting application is actually legitimate, rather than malicious code crafted by a spammer to just look like your application?

Before you can use OAuth2, your application has be be registered with Google. As part of this process Google issues you with a client secret, which you then have to build in to your application instance.  This application instance is also tied to redirect URIs for when the authorisation handshake is complete.

The upshot of this is that you can't really distribute an OAuth2-using app without each deployment having to go through the registration process.  If you try and distribute the secret with your application, then it's no longer a secret, and in any case, you can't know all of the URIs at which it may be deployed.

An approach I've taken with an application I'm working on is to have the application read a client secret file that has to be provided by the installer of the application, based on their own registration.  This has a format based on the JSON download that Google provides when you register an application.  It's something of a pain requiring every installer to go through this dance, but as things stand I don't believe there's an easier way that is also secure.

For example, I have an implementation of OpenID Connect authentication using Google that builds upon the [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) library, and uses a file format based on Google's client secrets file.  When a service is registered with Google to use OAuth2, there's a "client secrets" file that Google can provide that looks something like this:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "9876543210.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "secret-12345678901234567890",
    "client_email": "9876543210@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_x509_cert_url": 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/9876543210@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "redirect_uris": 
      [ "http://localhost:8000/annalist/login_done/", 
        "http://annalist-demo.example.org:8000/annalist/login_done/"
      ],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
  }
}
```

In my code, I use this file to initiate an OAuth2 flow using the `oauth2client` library, with code that looks like this:

```
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    clientsecrets_filename,
    scope=scope,
    redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri(login_done)
    )
```

So you can see that there's much more information than *just* the client id that is used when initiating the flow.  The full code of my implementation is at https://github.com/gklyne/annalist/blob/master/src/annalist_root/oauth2/views.py, beginning about line 273, but there's a lot more logic in that module that's to do with passing details back to a an application running in the Django framework.

I've also created [documentation](https://github.com/gklyne/annalist/blob/master/documents/openid-connect-setup.md) of the procedure I use to register the application with Google and deploy the client credentials.  Note that these instructions are for the identity service not the calendar API, and that the details are specific to my application, but I'm hoping there's enough commonality to help you on your way.

---

Looking to the future, the IETF are working on a spec for allowing automated registration of an OAuth2-using application instance.  I think this is the relevant specification: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-oauth-dyn-reg/.  It appears that it is currently (as of September 2014) being considered for standards track publication, but that doesn't say when it might be more widely available.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I really appreciate it. I'm a bit confused however as to how this works. So I have two fields so far: the client secret and client ID. I know that the ID is what identifies the client, but I thought the secret was a password of soarts. basically that it was what kept people from pretending to be my app and flooding google with requests. From what you stated, the client secret is generated per client. How does that work out? I'm sorry for the confusion, and thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Yes, the client ID *identifies* the client, but the client secret *authenticates* client.  You use them together.  I have a working OAuth2 module for Django at https://github.com/gklyne/annalist/blob/master/src/annalist_root/oauth2/views.py, which builds on @bitworker's `oauth2client` library.  The key step is about line 318, which accepts a "client secrets" file containing the client id, client secret and more".

Comment: I've added some sample code to my answer to try and flesh out what I say above.